# Quaternion lerp back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to `lerp` along the Z axis forth and back the same amount to avoid spinning (as my `sprite` is not a circular one). To do this I planned to random a `forward angle`, store it, `lerp` to it then `lerp` back with the same amount. However, this gives some weird popping as when the backwards rotations starts the starting angle wouldn't be the same, but it is. When I call it, I give it the same time to interpolate between. Some code:

```
IEnumerator LerpQuat(QuatLerpInput rotThis, float time, float leftBoundary, float rightBoundary)
{
    /*
     * we want to rotate forward, then backward the same amount
     * to avoid spinning. we store the given value to both of these.
    */

    Transform stuffToRot = rotThis.godRayGO.transform;

    float lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    switch (rotThis.rotState)
    {
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway):
            rotThis.deltaRot = Random.Range(leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
            while (timer < time)
            {
                stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(stuffToRot.rotation.x, stuffToRot.rotation.y,
                    Mathf.LerpAngle(rotThis.idleRot, rotThis.idleRot + rotThis.deltaRot, timer / time));
                timer += (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime);
                lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
                yield return null;
            }
            rotThis.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack;
            break;
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack):
            while (timer < time)
            {
                stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(stuffToRot.rotation.x, stuffToRot.rotation.y,
                    Mathf.LerpAngle(rotThis.idleRot + rotThis.deltaRot, rotThis.idleRot, timer / time));
                timer += (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime);
                lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
                yield return null;
            }
            rotThis.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway;
            break;
    }

}
public class QuatLerpInput
{
    public GameObject godRayGO;
    public float deltaRot;
    public float idleRot;
    public enum RotationStates
    {
        rotAway, setBack
    }
    public RotationStates rotState = RotationStates.rotAway;
    public QuatLerpInput(GameObject godRayGO)
    {
        this.godRayGO = godRayGO;
        deltaRot = godRayGO.transform.rotation.z;
        idleRot = godRayGO.transform.rotation.z;
    }
}
```

Edited `switch` with Quaternions:

```
switch (rotThis.rotState)
    {
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway):
            rotThis.deltaRot = Random.Range(leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
            Quaternion destination = new Quaternion(rotThis.idleQuat.x, rotThis.idleQuat.y, rotThis.idleQuat.z + rotThis.deltaRot, 1.0f);
            rotThis.deltaQuat = destination;
            while (timer < time)
            {
                stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotThis.idleQuat, rotThis.deltaQuat, timer/time);
                //stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(stuffToRot.rotation.x, stuffToRot.rotation.y,
                //    Mathf.LerpAngle(rotThis.idleRot, rotThis.idleRot + rotThis.deltaRot, timer / time));
                timer += (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime);
                lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

                yield return null;
            }
            rotThis.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack;
            break;
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack):
            while (timer < time)
            {
                stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rotThis.deltaQuat, rotThis.idleQuat, timer / time);
                //stuffToRot.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(stuffToRot.rotation.x, stuffToRot.rotation.y,
                //    Mathf.LerpAngle(rotThis.idleRot + rotThis.deltaRot, rotThis.idleRot, timer / time));
                timer += (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastTime);
                lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

                yield return null;
            }
            rotThis.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: If anyone stumbled accross this and couldn't help, please feel free to ask for clarification. I tried my best but I might have expressed meself unclear and I have still not found the answer on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone seeing this, I have found a solution.

```
void LerpQuat(QuatLerpInput rotThis, float time, float leftBoundary, float rightBoundary)
{
    /*
     * we want to rotate forward, then backward the same amount
     * to avoid spinning. we store the given value to both of these.
    */

    Transform stuffToRot = rotThis.godRayGO.transform;

    float lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    float timer = 0.0f;

    switch (rotThis.rotState)
    {
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway):
            rotThis.deltaRot = Random.Range(leftBoundary, rightBoundary);
            Quaternion destination = new Quaternion(rotThis.idleQuat.x, rotThis.idleQuat.y, rotThis.deltaRot, 1.0f);
            rotThis.deltaQuat = destination;
            rotThis.deltaEulerAngle = Vector3.forward * rotThis.deltaRot;               
            StartCoroutine(RotateMe(rotThis, rotThis.idleQuat, rotThis.deltaEulerAngle, initiateAlphaSwap));
            break;
        case (QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack):
            StartCoroutine(RotateMe(rotThis, rotThis.deltaQuat,-1.0f * rotThis.deltaEulerAngle, initiateAlphaSwap));
            break;
    }
}
IEnumerator RotateMe(QuatLerpInput whatToRotate,Quaternion fromWhere,Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)
{
    Quaternion fromAngle = fromWhere;
    Quaternion toAngle = Quaternion.Euler(whatToRotate.godRayGO.transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);
    toAngle = new Quaternion(toAngle.x, toAngle.y, toAngle.z, 1.0f);

    if(whatToRotate.rotState == QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack)
    {
        fromAngle = new Quaternion(whatToRotate.RotEndPos.x, whatToRotate.RotEndPos.y, whatToRotate.RotEndPos.z, 1.0f);
        toAngle = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
        whatToRotate.godRayGO.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromAngle, toAngle, t);
        yield return null;
    }
    if(whatToRotate.rotState == QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway)
    {
        whatToRotate.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.setBack;
        whatToRotate.RotEndPos = new Vector3(toAngle.x, toAngle.y, toAngle.z);
    }
    else
    {
        whatToRotate.rotState = QuatLerpInput.RotationStates.rotAway;
    }

}
```

The workaround was using `Quaternion.Lerp` continuosly in a `loop` and set the states **after the loop has finished**. This way it does what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lerping the angle, you should calculate the destination quaternion and use `Quaternion.Slerp` to interpolate to the random quaternion and back.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. So I should just give them the exact same X and Y and a different Z?

Comment: I edit my question with the code with Quaternions. Still doesn't work and does very strong movements.

Comment: For the record it does the exact same popping with the `Slerp`